# Is there WSDL for RequestSecurityToken / RequestSecurityTokenResponse

Tags: php, xml, wcf, soap, lamp

I'm working on project where a SoapClient is sending my server a RequestSecurityToken request from a .NET environment.

Normally this request would go to a .NET WCF service and the WCF service would return the RequestSecurityTokenReponse accordingly.

I'm using a LAMP environment for the server side and wanted to find out if there's a WSDL for RequestSecurityToken / RequestSecurityTokenResponse or if someone has a copy of the Envelop that contain the RequestSecurityTokenResponse.  Therefore, I'll be able to format the return data from my server correctly when returning it to the client.

Also in the RequestSecurityToken request there is a BinarySecret, do I need to use that to create the Security Token on my server before I return it to the client.

Here's the Envelope that I'm receiving the SoapClient:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:3c574ae0-51fd-4013-82fb-70763c0d0cee</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">/a:To>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2021-12-01T17:35:15.623Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2021-12-01T17:40:15.623Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid">
            <o:Username>xxx</o:Username>
            <o:Password>xxx</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
    <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
    <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
    <t:Entropy>
        <t:BinarySecret u:Id="23323" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">3433433</t:BinarySecret>
    </t:Entropy>
    <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
```

</s:Envelope>

Comment: You have a bunch of elements which should be defined inside the WSDL of the service, under a `WS-Policy` element. There is [a bunch of specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) that work with SOAP services. Your message shows WS-Addressing and some older/initial version of WS-Trust. Search for the namespaces and you should find whatever you are looking for ([like for example](https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/)). If you want to do these things with PHP you might be on your own as PHP SOAP implementations didn't bother with many WS-* specs.

Comment: Maybe you can look at these documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dvre/368ebe60-8acb-499c-a7f1-ad124ed98fc0 and  http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/errata01/os/ws-trust-1.4-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc325658942.